# Pyspark - Max / Min Parameter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a query. In Pyspark when we need to get total(SUM) based on (Key,Value), our query reads like:

```
RDD1 = RDD.reduceByKey(lambda x , y: x + y)
```

where as when we need to find MAX / MIN value for (Key,Value) our query reads like

```
RDD1 = RDD.reduceByKey(lambda x , y: x if x[1] >= y[1] else y)
```

Why when we Sum data not using `x[1]`, `Y[1]`, where as same is use for MAX / MIN?. Please clarify the doubt.

Rgd's

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong and you've taken this code out of context.  In both cases `x` and `y` refer to values.

```
lambda x , y: x if x[1] >= y[1] else y
```

is equivalent to:

```
lambda x, y: max(x, y, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

It compares values by their second element and means that each **value**:

- Is indexable (implements `__getitem__`).
- Has at least two elements.

Example

```
sc.parallelize([(1, ("a", -3)), (1, ("b", 3))]) \
  .reduceByKey(lambda x , y: x if x[1] >= y[1] else y).first()
```

will be `(1, ('b', 3))` because 3 is larger than -3.